# Нарушает ли данная архитектура принцип инверсии зависимости (S.O.L.I.D.)

Tags: java, проектирование, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть код:

```
public interface UIComponent {
  void userEventHandling();
}

public interface ServiceEventListener {
  void onServiceEvent();
}

public class UIComponentImpl implements UIComponent, ServiceEventListener {

  private Service service;

  public UIComponentImpl(Service service) {
    this.service = service;
  }

  @Override
  public void onServiceEvent() {
    //handling service event...
  }

  @Override
  public void userEventHandling(){
    service.doService();
  }
}

public interface Service {
  void doService();
}

public class ServiceImpl implements Service{

  private ServiceEventListener eventListener;

  public ServiceImpl(ServiceEventListener eventListener) {
    this.eventListener = eventListener;
  }

  @Override
  public void doService() {
    //service work...
    //work...
    serviceEvent();
    //work...
  }

  private void serviceEvent(){
    //service event for ServiceEventListener
    eventListener.onServiceEvent();
  }
}
```

Со стороны UIComponemt пользователь генерирует событие, его должен обработать Service. В процессе работы Service возникает другое событие. Его должен обработать ServiceEventListener, который реализован в UIComponentImpl. Нарушает ли данный код правило: 
**Модули верхнего уровня не должны зависеть от модулей нижнего уровня. Оба должны зависеть от абстракции.
Абстракции не должны зависеть от деталей. Детали должны зависеть от абстракций.**

Comment: давайте попробуем так: что именно вас смущает?

Comment: Смущает то что для обработки события, которое возникло в сервисе, приходится делать ServiceEventListener, который реализуется классом уровня View. Получается как бы циклическая зависимость View->Service, Service->View. Но похоже в данном случае от неё никак не избавится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае и `UIComponentImpl` и `ServiceImpl` получают в конструктор некие абстракции, а не используют какие-то конкретные реализации, что вполне соответствует принципу инверсии зависимостей.

Другой вопрос в том - не нарушает ли `UIComponentImpl` принцип единственной обязанности, из того же SOLID. Так как он отвечает и за `UIComponent` и за `ServiceEventListener`. Но этого количества кода не достаточно, чтобы это понять.

И еще хотелось бы добавить то, что если `UIComponentImpl` и `ServiceImpl` - это единственные классы, которые реализуют перечисленные выше интерфейсы и других их реализаций не предвидится, а для тестирования их не нужно подменять какими-либо заглушками, то тогда и не стоит создавать эти интерфейсы ради того, чтобы просто следовать неким принципам.

Comment: Сразу и не возможно предсказать, будут ли другие UIComponentImpl и ServiceImpl. Поэтому созданы интерфейсы. А по поводу принципа единственной обязанности - да. Скорее всего лучше реализовать  ServiceEventListener другим классом. Спасибо!

Comment: @Mikhail Если заранее не известно, то и не обязательно сразу создавать интерфейсы. Современные IDE позволяют быстро произвести рефакторинг в случае появления интерфейса вместо класса.

Comment: Это если есть исходный код того модуля, который использует конкретную реализацию